# How to list all tmux commands for a particular mode?

Tags: terminal, tmux

I know of `tmux`'s `:list-commands`, which displays a list of commands.

However, consider the following command:

```sh
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi y send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel "xclip -i -f -selection primary | xclip -i -selection clipboard"
```

What bothers me is that, e.g., `copy-pipe-and-cancel` doesn't show up in the command list above. How can I make `tmux` display a complete list of commands or a list of commands per mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no inbuilt method to show copy mode commands, they are in the manual.

Comment: Thank you, so `:list-commands` only display general commands not specific to any mode or some default mode? For the latter case, what's the specific name of that default mode?

Comment: The default isn't a mode and it doesn't have a name.

Comment: But where do the commands listed by `list-commands` apply if not to a specific mode? To all modes? Sorry, I'm new to tmux.

Comment: It depends most of them perform some action immediately, most don't care if the pane is in a mode. You can bind them to keys or run them from the command prompt or the shell. There are lots of examples in the manual.